# JSP error escape quotes in expression

Tags: jsp, if-statement, escaping, expression, quotes

I need to check type to display correct message like:

```
${row.type} <c:if test="${row.stype ==\"Note\" }">Important Note</c:if>
```

But the problem that escaping produce strange error:
   Unable to analyze EL expression due to lexical analysis error

How it can be fixed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quotes must not be escaped in EL. Use single quotes if the tag attribute is in double quotes, and vice-versa:

```
<c:if test="${row.stype == 'Note'}">Important Note</c:if>
```

or

```
<c:if test='${row.stype == "Note"}'>Important Note</c:if>
```